# General (rough) algorithm for transliterating a RTL language to a LTR language

Tags: javascript, parsing, transliteration

I am beginning thinking about how to [transliterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) a RTL string (i.e. arabic, hebrew) to a LTR string (i.e. the [romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization) of the sounds/letters). It's relatively straightforward if it's LTR -> LTR, but more tricky mentally for RTL -> LTR. For LTR -> LTR, you could have a simple mapping for each letter in *A* to each letter in *B*. Maybe multiple A's combined make a B in some cases, or a single a single A makes a chain of Bs.

```
a        b
-        -
X        1
YZ       2
ABC      3
D        456
E        78
```

Then given a string like `XYZYZDDEABC` you would get `122456456783`. Basic enough, though the actual algorithm would be a bit tricky because it might have to lookahead and have a prioritization on the elements. But this is the gist of it.

Now for a RTL -> LTR transformation, I'm confused on two levels. First, how do you iterate through a RTL string? The characters are *actually* in LTR order, correct? It's just the visual layout in browsers and such which makes it RTL. So from a code perspective, your RTL language is actually read LTR (it's not like we have to do anything in reverse or anything). Just making sure I'm interpreting this correctly. That would mean I can just do like the above LTR -> LTR transformation for all intents and purposes.

If it's not like that, and there's something else to consider, I would like to know generally how to do this. If a language is needed for a demo, then JavaScript would be good.

Comment: I don't have a preference, I simply want to know how to do it correctly.

Comment: IMO you need to reverse the string for such conversion, as visually if i try to apply some changes on RTL i expects changes to happen considering right hand side on string as starting point, i.e `CBA` i would expect it to be treated as `ABC` ( Reading from right to left ) not `CBA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. Text is stored in "logical order", which is the order it would be typed (or, in most cases, the order in which it is spoken). So you don't need to take directionality into account during transliteration.

Note that in many writing systems, including both Arabic and Hebrew, numbers are written "big-endian", with the most significant digit on the left. They are also typed in this order, meaning that the text is actually bidirectional. That is also the case when texts of different directionality are mixed together, such as when names written in Latin script are included in an Arabic or Hebrew document. Fortunately, you don't need to worry about that either, unless you're writing a Unicode renderer. (If you are, you'd need to read [Annex 9 to the Unicode standard](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/tr9-41.html), which goes into all the details of bidirectional rendering.)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the extra info about the Unicode standard, that's useful too.